# Name of probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question, terminology

Does this distribution have a name:

> $f(x) = yx^{y-1}$ for $0 < x<1$ and $y>0$?

It looks like an exponential distribution. Or is it a nameless distribution?

Comment: **Aside**: When $y \in \mathbb N$, this is the density function of the maximum of a sample of size $y$ of iid $\mathcal U(0,1)$ random variables.

Comment: This is a beta distribution with $\beta=1$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Answer (score 2):

As Byron Schmuland says, this is a [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with the second parameter $\beta=1$.

It is sometimes called a "[standard power-function distribution](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dVP-RTea5wcC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22standard%20power%20function%20distribution%22&source=bl&ots=G5rfunvHCX&sig=2522po7dAEiOTfCeXeiafiVxMWQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nhqOT4PZGYHZ8AOIodGqCw&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22standard%20power%20function%20distribution%22&f=false)".